# C# to generate automatically updating Excel charts

Tags: c#, excel, plot, charts, office-interop

I have a Windows Form with a data grid view where I can input some data. 
My C# code simply reads these data from the data grid view, processes it and then needs to plot the results. 
In particular, the results are stored in a list. There are also some additional data (which are intermediate results of the calculations) that are stored in two dimensional arrays. 
The point where I'm stuck is the plotting. I want to do this in Excel and I want to make it update dynamically whenever I change some input in the data grid view. 
The code below open an Excel workbook and pastes the data of the list in column A.

1. how can I add the two dimensional array in column B and C?
2. how can I plot these columns in a line chart?
3. how can I make the Excel chart update automatically as soon as I update some value in my data grid view (without opening every time a new Excel workbook)?

Thank you for the help.

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;
            using System.IO;
            using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

            namespace NewPoject
            {
                class plotter
                {   
                    public void plotGraphExcel_2D(List<double> x, double[,] y, double[,] yUP, double[,] yDOWN)
                    {
                        Excel.Application xlApp;
                        Excel.Workbook workbook;
                        Excel.Worksheet sheet;
                        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                        xlApp.Visible = true;
                        workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                        sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); 

                        var range = sheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
                        range.Value2 = "Scores";

                        //now the list
                        string cellName;
                        int counter = 2;
                        foreach (var item in x)
                        {
                            cellName = "A" + counter.ToString();
                            var range2 = sheet.get_Range(cellName, cellName);
                            range2.Value2 = item.ToString();
                            ++counter;
                        }

                        // How can I save the results of the array y in column B and C?
                        // How can I plot a line chart with the values I have pasted in column A, B and C?
                        // How can I make it update automatically when I change some value in the data grid view?
                    }
                }
            }
```